# Create Function error SQL SCRIPT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to create a function but i dont know whats wrong with it  . It gives the error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_numseq (@max_rows AS BIGINT,@min_rows AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
    AS 
    -- returns up to 4,294,967,296 records 
    WITH 
      lv0 AS (SELECT 0 AS g UNION ALL SELECT 0), 
      lv1 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv0 AS a CROSS JOIN lv0 AS b), 
      lv2 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv1 AS a CROSS JOIN lv1 AS b), 
      lv3 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv2 AS a CROSS JOIN lv2 AS b), 
      lv4 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv3 AS a CROSS JOIN lv3 AS b), 
      lv5 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv4 AS a CROSS JOIN lv4 AS b), 

      Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM lv5) 

      SELECT n FROM Nums where n >= @min_rows and n <= @max_rows ORDER BY n
    GO
```

Comment: Could you please also add the error message given?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the table the function returns, and insert into it, rather than selecting.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_numseq (@max_rows AS BIGINT,@min_rows AS BIGINT) 
RETURNS @t TABLE (n int)
AS 
begin                           
    -- returns up to 4,294,967,296 records 
    ;WITH 
      lv0 AS (SELECT 0 AS g UNION ALL SELECT 0), 
      lv1 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv0 AS a CROSS JOIN lv0 AS b), 
      lv2 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv1 AS a CROSS JOIN lv1 AS b), 
      lv3 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv2 AS a CROSS JOIN lv2 AS b), 
      lv4 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv3 AS a CROSS JOIN lv3 AS b), 
      lv5 AS (SELECT 0 AS g FROM lv4 AS a CROSS JOIN lv4 AS b), 

      Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM lv5) 
      insert @t
      SELECT n FROM Nums where n >= @min_rows and n <= @max_rows ORDER BY n
      return
end
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A few problems - you've specified `RETURNS TABLE` without then defining said table, inserting into it, missing return statement etc.

Here's a copy that should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_numseq
(
  @max_rows AS BIGINT,
  @min_rows AS BIGINT
)
RETURNS @t TABLE
(
  N INT
)
AS
  BEGIN
      -- returns up to 4,294,967,296 records 
      WITH lv0
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               UNION ALL
               SELECT 0),
           lv1
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               FROM   lv0 AS a
                      CROSS JOIN lv0 AS b),
           lv2
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               FROM   lv1 AS a
                      CROSS JOIN lv1 AS b),
           lv3
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               FROM   lv2 AS a
                      CROSS JOIN lv2 AS b),
           lv4
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               FROM   lv3 AS a
                      CROSS JOIN lv3 AS b),
           lv5
           AS (SELECT 0 AS g
               FROM   lv4 AS a
                      CROSS JOIN lv4 AS b),
           Nums
           AS (SELECT Row_number()
                        OVER (
                          ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n
               FROM   lv5)
      INSERT INTO @t(n)
      SELECT n
      FROM   Nums
      WHERE  n >= @min_rows
             AND n <= @max_rows
      ORDER  BY n

      RETURN
  END
```